# SSIS update DB2 database from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-update, db2

I have an SSIS package which imports full table data from DB2 database and loads in SQL Server on a daily basis. At the end of the day I need to post only updates (only some rows of table which are edited) to DB2 from SQL Server.

I have couple of options to do this task

1. Write a stored procedure using linked servers and update only required rows to DB2
2. Use script component in SSIS and perform row by row update.

Both of them can work, however I don't want to use either of them. Is there any other better solution apart from these which I can perform in SSIS?

*Note* : I cannot truncate and load all records from SQL Server to db2 as this is not a feasible solution.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, they have "timestamp" and "lastupdatedby" columns. That's how I'm able to get which records are updated.

Comment: Why don't you create a staging table on DB2 to insert the changes with SSIS and then update de main DB2 table from there?

Comment: How would you know if an alternative were "better" than the two solutions you describe?

Comment: @Vercelli : i guess staging table can benefit me only in the case - instead of writing query for modified records and get them in a buffer, staging table can store in a physical table. Rest of the complexity remains the same. Please let me know if I'm heading wrong

Comment: @Mustaccio : we have components which can insert data from a source to destination. I was looking for such a simply operation / procedure rather than me being imperative with the update query.

Comment: @Ramu - Not just that. The bulk insert on a empty staging table would be really fast. The update from staging table could be done all the rows at once (not row by row update like 2.) and in just one transaction. You could choose to truncate the staging table on the same transaction as update.

Comment: @Ramu -  In case of an update Error you can easily query staging table to gather/correct error.

Comment: @Vercelli - If I get u right, get only updated records and insert using oledb destination component to a db2 staging table, then another script component to execute query over DB2 for update from staging to actual table. Of course we can truncate staging when update is successful. Sounds a good plan to me rather than iterating record by record. But just want to check for any other options available. Otherwise this seems a better solution than my 2 options.

Comment: @Ramu Yes, you got it right.